# Android: make sure that specific activity retains in backstack

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to make so the every activity launches with **only one** main activity in the backstack, so I always can return to the main activity with back button as for example (for starting activities I use *startActivity()*):

1. Main Activity - Activity1 (back pressed) **returns** to Main
   Activity
2. Main Activity - Activity1 - Activity2 (back pressed) also
   **returns** to Main Activity

It looks like I need to use *FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK* flag on launching every new activity, but it clears Main Activity either. I've tried *FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP* works fine in the **1st** case, but not in the **2nd**.

If someone has the same problem, please help. Any thoughts appreciated! Thanks!

---

My main activity:

```
        <activity
        android:name=".activity.main.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value=".activity.search.SearchActivity" />

    </activity>
```

Comment: you required only mainActivity in the background ? no orher activity should open after backpress only mainActivity ? right ?

Comment: Don't know if this works, but maybe try calling this.finish() on every activity that's not your main activity when starting a new one?

Comment: are you also using `Fragment`s?

Comment: I think you should set parent activity for activity1 & 2 as MainActivity `android:parentActivityName=".activity.main.MainActivity"` link https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html

Comment: @EmmanuelMtali thanks, it worked for me!

Comment: Your welcome @ЛеопольдБлум

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @EmmanuelMtali mentioned, I used parent activity for this reason.

1. For activity different from Main, I set **meta-data** (and **android:parentActivityName**, **API > 16**) as follows:

   ```
       <activity
       android:name=".activity.user.LoginActivity"
       android:screenOrientation="portrait"
       android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
       android:launchMode="singleTop"
       android:parentActivityName=".activity.main.MainActivity">

       <meta-data
           android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
           android:value=".activity.main.MainActivity" />
   </activity>
   ```
2. When I need to start new activity I use array of intents and *startActivities()* method:

   ```
   public static Intent[] createIntentsWithMainActivityInStack(Context context, Intent topMostIntent) {
   TaskStackBuilder taskStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
   topMostIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);

   Intent[] intents =
           taskStackBuilder
                   .addNextIntentWithParentStack(topMostIntent)
                   .getIntents();

   return intents; }
   ```

and

```
Intent[] intents = createIntentsWithMainActivityInStack(context, new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class));
startActivities(intents);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set **FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY** flag while firing the intent of Main Activity in onBackPressed().

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that you call `finish()` when `Activity1` starts `Activity2`. This will ensure that your task stack looks like this: MainActivity->Activity2.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in every activity so that when you back press main activity opens:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTIVITYTHREE.this,MAINACTIVITY.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Didn't vote, but I think because it doesn't exactly answer the question. It loads the main activity new and doesn't use the possibly changed instance state

Comment: This is a horrible way to achieve this. And no, I didn't downvote either.